# Как сохранить голову односвязного списка в с++?

Tags: c++, указатели, список

```
struct list
{
    int x;
    list* next; 
};

void add(list* List, int Value) {
    List->x = Value;
    list* newList = new list;
    List->next = newList;
    newList->next = NULL;
    List = newList;
}

void show(list* List) {
    while (List->next != NULL) {
        cout << List->x << ' ';
        List = List->next;
    }
}

int main()
{
    list* MyList = new list;
    list* Begin = MyList; //Пытаюсь сохранить начало списка

    add(MyList, 2);       //Добавляем элементы 
    add(MyList, 3);       //в список,
    add(MyList, 4);       //смещая указатель 
    add(MyList, 5);       //на конец списка

    show(Begin);          //Выводит только последнее число в списке, 
                          //а нужно чтобы выводило все числа!
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

усложни немного свой list

```
struct element {
    element* next;
    int x;
};

struct list
{
    element* begin;
    element* current;

    list()
    {
         begin = NULL;
         current = NULL;
    }

    void add(value)
    {
        if (begin == NULL)
        {
            begin = new element;
            current = begin;
        }
        else
        {
            current->next = new element;
            current = current->next;
        }

        current->x = value;
        current->next = NULL;
    }
}
```

а получение списка с begin элемента начинай

**P.S.**

```
void show(list* List) {
    while (List->next != NULL) {
        cout << List->x << ' ';
        List = List->next;
    }
}
```

тут вижу ошибку - если у тебя всего 1 элемент (текущий существует, следующего нет) - у тебя ничего не выведется, потому что while не сработает. Мне кажется надо так:

```
void show(list* List) {
    while (List != NULL) { // Вот тут надо List != NULL, а не List->next != NULL
        cout << List->x << ' ';
        List = List->next;
    }
}
```

**P.P.S.**

А вот тут вижу вторую и ГЛАВНУЮ ошибку

```
void add(list* List, int Value) {
    List->x = Value;
    list* newList = new list;
    List->next = newList;
    newList->next = NULL;
    List = newList;
}
```

ты хочешь заменить указатель List, но не делаешь этого.
Твой код равносилен следующему:

```
void add(int res) {
    res = 5;
}
```

ничего не произойдет - res локальна
поэтому надо

```
void add(int& res) {
    res = 5;
}
```

а в твоем случае

```
void add(list&* List, int Value) {
```

А то у тебя что происходило? По указателю List ты работал - менял `->next` и `->value`, но сам List не менял ибо он был локален, в итоге фактически ты все писал в первый элемент, ну и память выделял почем зря.

Comment: при создании первого элемента у меня в любом случае его следующий элемент будет равен NULL вот: newList->next = NULL;

Comment: Как это List не меняется? Я уже по указателю его передаю! List у меня как раз таки постоянно меняется на последний элемент в списке и когда я передаю его в show(), то он показывает последний элемент - все верно. Проблема в том, что я хочу сохранить первый элемент списка, чтобы выводить весь список с него, а меня не получается(

Comment: P.S. Первый пример хороший, но тяжелый для восприятия лично мне, так как только начал изучать с++

Comment: P.P.S. если я сделаю вот так, то он выведет все элементы

Comment: add(MyList, 2);  
show(MyList);
add(MyList, 3);   
show(MyList);
add(MyList, 4);
show(MyList);
add(MyList, 5);      
show(MyList);

Comment: проверил ваш код, работает идеально, но сложновато...

Comment: в P.S. и P.P.S. я указал твои ошибки. Касательно PPS твоя главная ошибка - и-за того, что ты не используешь ссылку, то не можешь передавать указатель на новый (последний элемент) и как результат - ты всегда пишешь в первый (Begin) - поэтому и выводится у тебя только один (вроде последний) элемент. Ты можешь свою функцию add вместо void объявить как list* и в конце функции делать return list, тогда будет myList = add(List, 2); myList = add(List, 3);... и т.д. - тогда должно заработать. А по поводу PS - пошагово пройти свой код и увидишь, что надо делать while (List != NULL), List->next != NULL

Comment: ок, спасибо большое вы очень помогли. Можете еще, примерно, накидать как сделать двусвязный список. Я понял, что тут просто еще указатель на предыдущий элементы должен быть. Сделал так и пытаюсь вывести список наоборот, но не выходит

Comment: два курса в техе изучал паскаль, ща на 3ем перешли на с++ и с указателей голова разъезжается. Где можно найти объяснение для тупых по указателям и ссылкам? Я читал, что нашел, вроде чет понял, но чет все равно не понял)

Comment: поищи "с++ ссылки для начинающих". А так - ссылка по сути скрытый указатель